# Cobol-db2 bind process

Tags: db2, cobol, db2-zos

I have a question regarding the db2 bind process.. Is the sql query stored in any of the catalog tables after the bind process? Can we execute a cobol-db2 program after if the dbrm was deleted just before submitting the job?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [COBOL DB2 program](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446455/cobol-db2-program)

Comment: Which OS?  DB2 LUW and DB2 z/OS are often different.

Answer (score 0):

On z/OS if the DBRM was processed in a bind step it will be in the package tables.  The DBRM is no longer needed and the program will execute.  This is simple to test and validate.